# count comparisons using linear search in java

Tags: java, if-statement, count, return, do-while

My code is:

```
public static int linearSearch(int array[], int key){

    /*
    Description: Performs linear search on an array for a specified value
    Parameters:  int array of values and int key which item to be searched
    Returns: int indicating how many times number is found 
    */

    boolean found = false;
    int numberOfComparisons = 0;
    int index = 0;

    // Loop which breaks if number found or all numbers checked
    do{
        // Check key against current array value
        if (array[index] == key){
            found = true;
        }// if
        index++;
        numberOfComparisons++;
    }

    while(found && (index < array.length));

    // Return statements
    System.out.println("Number of comparisons with linear search: " + numberOfComparisons);
    if (found) return numberOfComparisons;
    else return -1;
}// linear search
```

how do I count how many times the number is found?

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `for` loop to iterate over the entire array once and check each element. Using `found` as part of the looping condition does not make sense, as it is necessary to go through the entire array at least once to count the number of times a particular element appears.

```
int times = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   if(array[i] == key){
      ++times;
   }
}
return times;
```

A for-each loop can be used to simplify this, as the index is not needed.

```
int times = 0;
for(int num: array){
   if(num == key){
     ++times;
   }
}
return times;
```